# Ubuntu 20.04 Installing Wine Has Downgraded Packages, can't see new versions

Tags: apt, package-management, wine

I've been having strange issues with Ubuntu 20.04 since I installed it. Most recently, I was trying to use wine to play games. Wine wasn't working as normal and kept failing with strange bugs. So, I uninstalled it with `sudo apt-get remove wine` and tried to reinstall. This failed as well, with a message about broken held packages (I didn't think at the time to save the messages, so please bear with me) and dependency problems. Something along the lines of `wine requires wine64/wine32 which will not be installed.`

I was totally confused. Anyway, after a couple hours of googling, nothing was working, so I attempted to install these packages manually with a couple `sudo apt-get`s. However, when I attempted to install wine64, this happened:

```
$ sudo apt-get install wine64
[sudo] password for [omitted]: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  [omitted, large list of standard "support" type packages]
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  wine
Suggested packages:
  q4wine winbind winetricks playonlinux wine-binfmt dosbox exe-thumbnailer
  | kio-extras wine64-preloader
Recommended packages:
  wine32
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  bind9-dnsutils calibre calibre-bin deja-dup discord eog evince file-roller
  firefox fraidycat fwupd fwupd-signed gnome-calendar gnome-logs graphviz
  gstreamer1.0-packagekit haguichi inkscape libepub0 libevdocument3-4
  libevview3-3 libkf5filemetadata-bin liblove0 libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra
  libopusfile0 libpodofo0.9.6 libproxy1-plugin-gsettings
  libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk3
  libsdl2-mixer-2.0-0 libssl-dev libtss2-esys0 libzip5 linux-generic-hwe-20.04
  linux-headers-5.8.0-34-generic linux-headers-5.8.0-36-generic
  linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04 love nautilus-image-converter netplan.io
  obs-studio peek qemu-system qemu-system-arm qemu-system-mips
  qemu-system-misc qemu-system-ppc qemu-system-s390x qemu-system-sparc
  qemu-system-x86 rsyslog samba shotwell simple-scan spice-vdagent
  squashfs-tools teams transmission-gtk ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-desktop-minimal
  ubuntu-minimal ubuntu-standard uuid-runtime vino whoopsie
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  wine wine64
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 66 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 266 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,826 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
```

Without really reading the above, I just hit Y and a bunch of programs I use were removed, like libreoffice and firefox. Panicking, I reinstalled them with `sudo apt-get`, but now firefox is stuck in version 75 (Current version is 84), libreoffice is also behind a few versions, and nothing I do will allow me to even "see" the new versions of these packages. Apt-get doesn't seem to even know they exist and keeps telling me that I'm at the latest version of each package. I installed synaptic and aptitude (they installed normally) and they also tell me I have the latest versions of each package. Oddly, other packages like discord have installed completely normally. At this point, I've no idea whats going on.

Any help would be appreciated. I'll edit this post with the output of any commands that people want me to run.

EDIT 1:
Result of `apt-cache policy wine64 wine32 wine`

```
wine64:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.0-3ubuntu1
  Version table:
     5.0-3ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
wine32:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.0-3ubuntu1
  Version table:
     5.0-3ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages
wine:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.0-3ubuntu1
  Version table:
     5.0-3ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages
```

Edit 2: Sources

```
/etc/apt/source.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
/etc/apt/source.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted
/etc/apt/source.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main universe restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-ubuntu-haguichi-focal.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/haguichi/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/bartbes-ubuntu-love-stable-focal.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/bartbes/love-stable/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list:deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/obsproject-ubuntu-obs-studio-focal.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list:deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/teams.list:deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable main
```

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy wine64 wine32 wine` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert added.

Comment: Also please show the list of the repositories by `grep ^deb -r /etc/apt/ --include=*.list`. If it is long - use pastebin

Comment: @N0rbert added that as well.

Comment: Your repositories are completely messed. They should contain *main universe multiverse restricted* in all sections of *focal*.

Comment: @N0rbert this *appears* to have worked. By copy pasting from the second part of that answer into `/etc/apt/sources.list` and then running the `sed` command I was able to update firefox to the latest version (84). I'm going to run `apt-get upgrade` overnight, as a lot of stuff needs to be upgraded and my internet is supremely slow, will update tomorrow morning and accept the "similar question" if everything works. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try pasting and running these commands in the terminal:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

```
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
```

```
sudo apt-key add winehq.key
```

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main'
```

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

```
dpkg-reconfigure wine-stable-amd64 wine-stable wine-stable-i386
```

Comment: Non-reasonable copy-pasting will make situation even worse. Please remove your answer.

Comment: @N0rbert this is supposed to work though, it will download the new key and install the new version.